# Pod error when run on iPad Retina or real device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoapods

Here is my Pod file

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target "Earcrush" do
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'ECSlidingViewController'
pod 'KGModal'
pod 'AMPopTip'
pod 'WYPopoverController'
pod 'UITextView+Placeholder'
pod 'SVPullToRefresh'
pod 'XCDYouTubeKit'
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'
pod 'M13ProgressSuite'
pod 'PINRemoteImage'
pod 'BLKFlexibleHeightBar'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'GoogleAPIClient'
pod 'GoogleAPIClient/YouTube'
pod 'GTMOAuth2'
end
```

When I run my project on any iPhone simulator, it will run successful
However, when I try run on iPad Retina (iOS8 or iOS9) I got the error below. I have tried clean project, reopen Xcode but no luck

[image]

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_M13ProgressViewPie", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IPProgressViewPie.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FacebookStyleBarBehaviorDefiner", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ECSearchStyleBarBehaviorDefiner in ECSearchStyleBarBehaviorDefiner.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WYPopoverTheme", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ECBaseMenuViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceYouTube", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SimpleYoutube.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryYouTube", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SimpleYoutube+Upload.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PINRemoteImageManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ECDataManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLYouTubeVideo", referenced from:
  ... 
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

What wrong with my Pod? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Could you fix this one?

Comment: sorry @zeeawan I still not solve this problem, still looking for the answer